# Unhandled Runtime Error, TypeError: tasks.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to complete my first todo-app in next js 13 using typescript but whenever I try to add a task in my task list I get the error given below 
**Unhandled Runtime Error**

*TypeError: tasks.map is not a function.*

> I have prvided the code from  page.tsx file below:

```
"use client"
import "./globals.css";
import { Button, Flex, ListItem, UnorderedList, Text, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function Home() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(["1", "2", "3"]);
  const [Item, setItem] = useState("");
function removeItem(taskName){
  setTasks(
    tasks.filter((task) => {
      return task!= taskName;
  })
  );
}
function AddItem(taskName){
  if(Item!="" && !tasks.includes(Item));
  let temp=tasks
  temp.push(Item);
  setTasks(Item);
  setItem("");
}
  return (
    <Flex
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      flexDirection="column"
    >
      <UnorderedList>
        {tasks.map((task) => {
          return (
            <ListItem key={task.index}>
              {task}
              <Button
                ml={10}
                onClick={() => {
                  removeItem(task); 
                }}>
                Remove Item
              </Button>
            </ListItem>
          )
        })}
      </UnorderedList>
      <Input
        placeContent="item name"
        value={Item}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setItem(e.target.value);
        }}>
      </Input>
<Button onClick={AddItem}>
  Add Item
</Button>
    </Flex>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the item isn't an array that's why it is throwing this error. So,
update your function by adding this code, I believe it'll solve your error:

```
 function AddItem(taskName) {
  if (Item != '' && !tasks.includes(Item)) {
    setTasks([...tasks, Item]);
    setItem('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the function `AddItem` to recreate the `tasks` array using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead:

```js
function AddItem(taskName){
  if(Item!="" && !tasks.includes(Item));
  let temp=[...tasks]
  temp.push(Item);
  setTasks(Item);
  setItem("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `tasks` to an individual item here:

```
setTasks(Item);
```

I imagine you want `temp` here instead of `Item`:

```
setTasks(temp);
```

If `item` is anything other than an array, the map function will not be valid and throw an error.

Also, in your `AddItem` function, you're mutating state and your `if` statment isn't actually wrapping anything so I would just rewrite the whole thing to the following:

```
function AddItem(taskName) {
  if (Item != '' && !tasks.includes(Item)) {
    setTasks([...tasks, Item]);
    setItem('');
  }
}
```

I'm assuming you have plans for `taskName`.

Hope this helps.